# Does Wordpress store post text as html or as plain text?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wysiwyg

## Text or HTML

I would like to know how WP stores its raw data in the mySQL database. Does its store as plain text like we see in the wysiwyg editor or does it store it with all the html tags?

Or is there something else that it does to the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postdata are stored as raw text. Formatting are done once the post is displayed.

The template tag, [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) show exactly what happens to raw content. In short, `the_content()` uses [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) which in short returns the raw `post_content` field. You will see the difference between

```
the_content();
```

and

```
echo get_the_content();
```

The raw content which `the_content()` uses from `get_the_content()` are run through a couple of filters (*`the_content` filters to be exact*) which adds the proper formatting to the text.

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Answer (score 1):

It stores as raw in MySQL DB. Here's a screenshot from Posts table:

[image]

Comment: ok cool (+1) but in that case how does it know how to format the content since its just plain text in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

To reply to your comment question: That is up to the caller of the database data. In Wordpress it would probably be a php call (but could also be Ajax, JavaScript, etc).

In high level terms I might have a function get_posts() which queries the database for some post data. When get_posts gets the data it is its job to interpret the data, usually we have an idea of how we should interpret the data based on where in the database it is and how it is organized.

The database data is akin to writing your post content out in note pad. It has no (very little) idea what the data represents.

Some data in the database is stored as an number, some as text, etc. If you pull up the posts table you will find the entire body of your blog posts. If you used html etc it will all be there as if you typed up the post in notepad.